# Unable to delete path

Tags: android, android-studio

Please bear with me, as I am fairly new to Android studio.

I am trying to run my app, Every time I run it I get error: `unable to delete path`, I have tried to delete the folder manually, it works for the first run then the same error show again in another folder. Any help please.
What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'. 
Failed to delete: D:\AndroidProjects\test\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy content of your new google-services.json file,open your existing google-services.json file and just pase the data.

Comment: What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: Could not delete path 'D:\AndroidProjects\test\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-in'.